# Why doesn't my crontab -e execute the .sh script?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

In `sudo crontab -e` I have this:

```
*/2 * * * * date >> /home/rki/test.log
*/5 * * * * sudo sh /home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh
```

`*/2 * * * * date >> /home/rki/test.log` works without a problem, writing every 2 minutes into the `test.log` file.

It just won't execute the `backup.sh` script which has this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Remove previous backups
#sudo rm dokuwiki-backup*.tar.gz

# Set backup name
name=dokuwiki-backup_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')

# Backup stuff
/bin/tar -zcvf "$name.tar.gz" /var/lib/docker/volumes/dokuwiki_data
```

I can do `sudo sh dokuwiki_backup.sh` fine without a problem. The bash script is `chmod`ed `0777` and `chown rki:rki`.

What's that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tasks that need elevated permissions should be uploaded to cron with `sudo crontab -e` and should not contain sudo, so try with `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh`

Comment: 1. Don't put sudo in crontab 2. use absolute paths.

Comment: Is `/home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh
` not an absolute path?

Comment: and never do `chmod 0777`. never use the 3rd 7. 0700 or 0750 for scripts is the best security when you know the user that executes it. @Grumpyol'Bear it is but `sh` does not have one. It is best to always use paths even it the path is inside the default for cron We do not know what your systems path is inside cron ;)

Comment: I just tested `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh` no dice.  `*/2 * * * * date >> /home/rki/test.log` still works, still no backup.

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear, 1. It may even be necessary to put absolute paths inside the shellscript. The reason is that the environment used by `cron` can very bare-bone (you cannot expect it to be the same as what you get as a logged in user); 2. Did you use `sudo crontab -e` ?

Comment: Yes, always `sudo crontab -e`, I want it as root not rki. Otherwise I'd go `crontab -e` for rki cronjobs.

Comment: 1. I suggest that you put full path onto the call of `date` too; 2. It is not compatible to call the script with `/bin/sh` and at the same time have the shebang `#!/bin/bash` in its first line. Either call with the shell program or use the shebang. In the latter case the script must also be executable.

Comment: Fuck all that, I'm just gonna do it manually. Fucking shit not working...

Comment: Maybe it works just fine, but your `$name.tar.gz` is relative and you don't know where it is ?

Comment: Ah shite... @pLumo, that was it indeed. Everything in ./root/ . Fucks sake...

Comment: Good catch @pLumo :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you add your cronjob via `sudo crontab -e`, it will run as `root`.

- No need for `sudo`, use:

  ```
  */5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh
  ```
- The default working directory should be `root`s `$HOME`, so usually `/root`. You can find `$name.tar.gz` there. But better to use absolute paths, e.g.:

  ```
  /bin/tar -zcvf "/home/rki/Backups/$name.tar.gz" /var/lib/docker/volumes/dokuwiki_data
  ```

Answer (score -1):

To run cronjobs with full root environment use this command

```
*/5 * * * * su - root -c '/home/rki/docker-compose-stuff/dokuwiki/backups/dokuwiki_backup.sh'
```

Comment: No dice. Doesn't work.

Comment: Your script might have an error. Try to run it from command line.